Find sleep sessions out of sleep stage data with pandas
I have sleep data from Apple Health Kit which looks similar to this
startDate   endDate value   sourceName
0   2024-06-03 22:26:00+02:00   2024-06-03 22:46:00+02:00   HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepCore  AppleWatch
1   2024-06-03 22:46:00+02:00   2024-06-03 22:49:00+02:00   HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAwake   AppleWatch
2   2024-06-03 22:49:00+02:00   2024-06-04 00:56:00+02:00   HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepREM   AppleWatch
3   2024-06-04 00:56:00+02:00   2024-06-04 03:56:00+02:00   HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepCore  AppleWatch
4   2024-06-04 05:56:00+02:00   2024-06-04 07:56:00+02:00   HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepREM   AppleWatch
5   2024-06-04 22:40:00+02:00   2024-06-05 07:48:00+02:00   HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepCore  AppleWatch

I would like to get a list of sleep sessions (start, end) with the sums of all stages that are within that session (sessions grouped by device ). Data is not always continuous (see between row 3 & 4). The gap should be treated as Awake. The data should then look similar to this
bedTime wakeTime    duration    HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepCore_duration HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepREM   HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAwake
0   2024-06-03 22:26:00+02:00   2024-06-04 07:56:00+02:00   9.267   3.133   4.108   2.025
1   2024-06-04 22:40:00+02:00   2024-06-05 07:48:00+02:00   9.133   9.133   0.000   0.000

What would be a good way of doing this? You can use the following data to import
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {
        "startDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-03 22:26:00+0200"),
        "endDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-03 22:46:00+0200"),
        "value": "HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepCore",
        "sourceName": "AppleWatch"
    },
    {
        "startDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-03 22:46:00+0200"),
        "endDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-03 22:49:00+0200"),
        "value": "HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAwake",
        "sourceName": "AppleWatch"
    },
    {
        "startDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-03 22:49:00+0200"),
        "endDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-04 00:56:00+0200"),
        "value": "HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepREM",
        "sourceName": "AppleWatch"
    },
    {
        "startDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-04 00:56:00+0200"),
        "endDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-04 03:56:00+0200"),
        "value": "HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepCore",
        "sourceName": "AppleWatch"
    },
    {
        "startDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-04 05:56:00+0200"),
        "endDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-04 07:56:00+0200"),
        "value": "HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepREM",
        "sourceName": "AppleWatch"
    },
    {
        "startDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-04 22:40:00+0200"),
        "endDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-05 07:48:00+0200"),
        "value": "HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepCore",
        "sourceName": "AppleWatch"
    }
]

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

And the code I tried was the following.
# Sort the DataFrame by startDate and sourceName
df = df_orig.sort_values(['sourceName', 'startDate'])

# Function to identify sleep sessions
def identify_sessions(group):
    return (group['startDate'] - group['startDate'].shift() > timedelta(hours=3)).cumsum()

# Group records into sessions, respecting device boundaries
df['session'] = df.groupby('sourceName', group_keys=False).apply(identify_sessions)

# Create a new DataFrame for sleep sessions
sleep_sessions = []

for (source, session), group in df.groupby(['sourceName', 'session']):
    bed_time = group['startDate'].min()
    wake_time = group['endDate'].max()
    total_duration = (wake_time - bed_time).total_seconds() / 3600  # in hours
    
    # Calculate duration for each sleep stage
    stage_durations = group.groupby('value').apply(lambda x: (x['endDate'] - x['startDate']).sum().total_seconds() / 3600)
    
    session_data = {
        'sourceName': source,
        'bed_time': bed_time,
        'wake_time': wake_time,
        'total_duration': total_duration,
        'asleep_duration': stage_durations.get('HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleep', 0),
        'in_bed_duration': stage_durations.get('HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisInBed', 0),
        'core_duration': stage_durations.get('HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepCore', 0),
        'deep_duration': stage_durations.get('HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepDeep', 0),
        'rem_duration': stage_durations.get('HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepREM', 0),
        'awake_duration': stage_durations.get('HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAwake', 0)
    }
    sleep_sessions.append(session_data)

# Create the final DataFrame
sleep_sessions_df = pd.DataFrame(sleep_sessions)


Hi, is your code not working or are you looking for an improved way to do it? Also, could you provide the several duration data (wake, asleep, in bed, etc.) you used?
